# ng-if check on an filter input in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple filter that puts one of two statements, based on if a input from SQL is true

```
    app.filter('yesNo', function() {
      return function(input) {
          return (input == '1') ? 'Skal tjekkes!' : 'Alt OK';
      }
  });
```

And then should change a menu item based on that;

```
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-ng-click="statusFilter = 'Ny ordre'">New Orders
      <div ng-if="input == '1' | outdated">
          <p>Needs to be checked: {{(orders | filter:{status:'ny ordre', outdated: '1'}).length}}</p>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="!input == '1' | outdated">Shows regardless</div>

      </a></li>
```

I am missing something, just no idea what. :(

Comment: There is a `'` too much in `ng-if="!input == '1'' | outdated"`

Comment: Thanks, missed that, but Im afraid its just showing both items

Comment: If I put             <div ng-if=!"input == '1' | outdated">Shows regardless</div>
It will stop showing it, but it will still show the other even if I know that is 0

Comment: Why would you put `!` outside the quotation marks? That's not even valid SGML. My suggestion was to use `input != '1'`.

Comment: Yes ok, I forgot to mention I tried that as well, and it just shows regardless :/

Answer (score 1):

You have an example here for how to use a custom filter function: http://jsfiddle.net/alexdumitrescu/zv6cf7nq/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .filter('myfilter', function() {
    return function(orders) {
      return orders.filter(function(order) {
        return order.outdated == '1';
      })
    }
  });

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.orders = [{
    status: 'my order1',
    outdated: '1'
  }, {
    status: 'my order2',
    outdated: '0'
  }];
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{orders | myfilter}}
</div>
```